# Write a function to find the maximum value of: () = −5 + sqrt(4−^2) by applying gradient descent: +1=−′()

Tags: python

The return value of x in f_gradient_descent(0, 0.01, 1000) is not -2.17 (max). Would you please have a look? Thank you so much!

```
import math

def f(x):
    return x-5 + math.sqrt(4-x**2)
 
def f_derivative(x):
    return 1 + 1/(2*math.sqrt(4-x**2))*(-2*x)

def f_gradient_descent(x0, eta, n_step):
"""
    Parameter:
        x0: Start point
        eta: Learning rate
        n_step: algorithm will stop after `n_step` cycle
"""
    x0 = 1.23
    eta = 0.001
    for _ in range(n_step):
        x0 = x0 - eta * f_derivative(x0)
        if abs(f_derivative(x0)) < 0.00001:
            break
    return f(x0)

assert f_gradient_descent(0, 0.01, 1000) - (-2.17) < 1e-4
```

Comment: Sorry for the trivia question, but how come you have fancy unicode characters to write `()`, but not for `x²` ? :D

Comment: Sorry for not being consistent. I just copy that expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few mistakes in the code.

- To arrive at the peak you have to ascend, not descend. So you have to *increase* `x0` if the derivative is positive.
- The values for `x0` and `eta` that are passed to the function are ignored because they are overwritten inside. `eta = 0.001` might be too small to arrive at the maximum within 1000 steps.
- In order to evaluate the result, you have to use the *absolute* value of the difference between the actual and the expected result.
- The actual maximum is -2.1716..., not -2.17, which is more than `1e-4` away.